# CV header bar with overlapping picture

Tags: header-footer, cv, overlap

I am trying to figure out how to do the following, but I'm at my wit's end.
How should I go about this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, done with `tabularx, enumitem` and simple `\rule` commands?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c >{\bfseries}Xb{2.5cm}}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} & \LARGE Name & \begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt, after=\vskip-\baselineskip]\item{} \rule[0.5ex]{2cm}{1pt}\strut\item {} \rule[0.5ex]{2cm}{1pt}\item {} \rule[0.5ex]{2cm}{1pt}
\end{itemize} \\
\enspace \smash{\color{RoyalBlue!20!DeepSkyBlue}\rule[-0.7cm]{1.2cm}{1.8cm}}& \footnotesize Some additional text \\[1cm]
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: To have a topbar that spreads over the whole sheet  of paper, you can load `eso-pic` and use this slightly modified code:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{c >{\bfseries}Xb{2.5cm}}
......
\end{tabularx}%
}}
```

Comment: I'm very impressed you got the example so closely mimicked! The top bar should however span the whole page, is it difficult to do so?

Comment: @Ayam: Would it be only  for the first page, or for each page of the document?

Comment: only the first page indeed. Thanks for putting in effort.
Might I ask where you learned these things so well?

Comment: I've been using LaTeX for more than 25 years… I'll add a suggestion for your specific case in a moment.